# process.env.CLIENT_ID works in function but not as a global variable in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use oAuth to work with googleapi

I am using .env to keep secret variables hidden with .gitignore

My problem is that if I try to define

```
CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID
```

Outside of the function as a global variable, when I run the variable and console log it, it returns undefined.

However, if I try to define it outside of the function and console log it inside it shows *undefined*

If I set my controller file like this it works

```
const passport = require('passport')
const validator = require('validator')
const User = require('../models/User')
const Company = require('../models/Company')
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const axios = require('axios');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const dayjs = require('dayjs')



  exports.googleAuthCode = (req, res) => {

   let CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
   let CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
   let REDIRECT_URL =  process.env.REDIRECT_URL;


   const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
   const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL,


  );

    console.log('running googleAuthCode')

    console.log('process.env.CLIENT_ID ', process.env.CLIENT_ID)
    console.log('process.env.CLIENT_SECRET ', process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
    console.log('process.env.REDIRECT_URL ', process.env.REDIRECT_URL)
    console.log('CLIENT_ID ', CLIENT_ID)
    console.log('CLIENT_SECRET ', CLIENT_SECRET)
    console.log('REDIRECT_URL ', REDIRECT_URL)


    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('authURL: ',authUrl)
    res.redirect(authUrl);


  }
```

If I set my controller like this it doesn't work:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const validator = require('validator')
const User = require('../models/User')
const Company = require('../models/Company')
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const axios = require('axios');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

   let CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
   let CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
   let REDIRECT_URL =  process.env.REDIRECT_URL;


   const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
   const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL,


  );

  exports.googleAuthCode = (req, res) => {

   

    console.log('running googleAuthCode')

    console.log('process.env.CLIENT_ID ', process.env.CLIENT_ID)
    console.log('process.env.CLIENT_SECRET ', process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
    console.log('process.env.REDIRECT_URL ', process.env.REDIRECT_URL)
    console.log('CLIENT_ID ', CLIENT_ID)
    console.log('CLIENT_SECRET ', CLIENT_SECRET)
    console.log('REDIRECT_URL ', REDIRECT_URL)


    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('authURL: ',authUrl)
    res.redirect(authUrl);


  }
```

I am using dotenv

I am using MVC setup,

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './config/.env'})
```

Is in my server.js file and exported to my controller file.

If you can shed some light on to how i can get this working as a global variable it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the `dotenv` imported in the very first line?

Comment: I had assumed that dotenv must be set up correctly as the function is able to read let CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID; if it is declared inside of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help!

The answers were right that I dad to import `dotenv` into the controller file that I wanted.

But I had to do it in the format

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: './config/.env'})
```

Once I added the path it worked no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `dotenv` is imported above all other modules.

Assume that I have two files inside my project: `main.js` and `utils.js`.

```js
// main.js
const { func1 } = require('./utils.js');
require('dotenv').config();
func1();
```

```js
// utils.js
console.log(process.env.SOME_SECRET);

exports.func1 = function() {
  console.log(process.env.SOME_SECRET);
}
```

In this case, the result would be like this:

```js
undefined
SECRET
```

The reason is that at the moment when the interpreter starts and interprets each line, the global env variable is `undefined`, and after the `dotenv` module is interpreted and processed, the environment variables sit in RAM and get values.

Therefore, in the last line where `func1` is executed, the environment variable has value.

That's why it is recommended to import `dotenv` at the very first line in the main file.

So the correct way would be like this:

```js
// main.js
require('dotenv').config();
const { func1 } = require('./utils.js');
func1();
```